# Hive Error on Join with multiple tables

Tags: hadoop, join, hive

I encounter a strange error when attempting to do a multi table join in Apache Hive. My query is of the form below:

```
insert into table1 (col1,col2,col3,col4) 
select a.col1, 'MyTextHere' ,sum(a.col3),b.col1 ,'tester' from tableA a 
join  tableB b on (b.col1=a.col1) and (b.col2=a.col3) and (b.col4=a.col4) and (b.col5=a.col5) 
join tableC c on (c.col1=a.col4)
WHERE  ( (a.col8='¤' AND b.col3='test') OR b.col3<>'test' )
group by a.col1,b.col1;
```

Executing this query results in the following error:

> org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException:Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:373 extraneous input '_SYNTHJOIN_258a8910___apv_' expecting ) near 'EOF':

I googled all over but couldnt find a resolution to this problem.
The tables are ORC and bucketed. I am running Hive 1.2 on Ambari Hortonworks HDP-2.3.
Are the extranous characters placed in the where clause causing this error?

Please help.

Comment: Is your select query working correctly????

Comment: Strangely enough, queries of this type either executes properly or throws a parse exception as described above. 
The select of this query, often, reports the same error.

Comment: Any idea @KishoreKumarSuthar?

Comment: select a.col1, 'MyTextHere' ,sum(a.col3),b.col1 ,'tester' from tableA a 
join  tableB b on (b.col1=a.col1) and (b.col2=a.col3) and (b.col4=a.col4) and (b.col5=a.col5) 
join tableC c on (c.col1=a.col4) , is this query working or not

Comment: as soon as the third join is entered, this synthjoin error crops up.

Comment: select a.col1, 'MyTextHere' ,sum(a.col3),b.col1 ,'tester' from tableA a 
join  tableB b on (b.col1=a.col1) and (b.col2=a.col3) and (b.col4=a.col4) and (b.col5=a.col5) . mean 2 tables join result is correct